# Send HTTP request from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, http, request

I use `HttpListener` in C# to get HTTP requests. I need to send requests using Java. I've tried sending requests using `HttpURLConnection` and `DataOutputStream`, but the C# code doesn't receive any requests.

I assume the problem is with Java, since I've created a small test application in C# which sends requests using the `HttpWebRequest` object, and everything worked fine.

What can possibly cause this issue?

This is a snippet from my C# code:

```
        Listener = new HttpListener();
        Listener.Start();
        Listener.Prefixes.Add(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", "127.0.0.1", "14141"));
        HttpListenerContext context = Listener.GetContext();
```

This is a snippet from my Java code:

```
     String message = "test message";
     URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:14141/");

     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 

     connection.setDoOutput(true);
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
     connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
     connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(message.getBytes().length));
     connection.setUseCaches (false);

     DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
     wr.writeBytes(message);

     writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
     writer.write(message);
```

Comment: Could you paste your java code please?

Comment: Maybe you could post the relevant C# and Java code that shows what you've been trying. There might be a bug in there, or an assumption that is wrong.

Comment: This is about the time I'd turn on Wireshark and see what's going across the wire.

Comment: I hasve code that sends from Java to C#.  Like others have said, please post some sample code.